# How to export excel sheet in java servlet with out using Maven?

Tags: java, excel, maven, export

Actually i tried to export data in excel sheet and i have following code-

```
//Blank workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
//Create a blank sheet
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("User Data");
User user = new User();
ArrayList objcets = (ArrayList) user.fetchAll(request);
// first row for header
int rowNum = 1;
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
int cellNum = 0;

// dynamic header sumbitted from form
if(request.getParameter("id")!=null && !request.getParameter("id").isEmpty())
{
    cellNum++;
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("Id");
}
if(request.getParameter("fullName")!=null && !request.getParameter("fullName").isEmpty())
{
    cellNum++;
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("Full Name");
}
if(request.getParameter("userName")!=null && !request.getParameter("userName").isEmpty())
{
    cellNum++;
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("User Name");
}
if(request.getParameter("department")!=null && !request.getParameter("department").isEmpty())
{
    cellNum++;
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("Department");
}
if(request.getParameter("email")!=null && !request.getParameter("email").isEmpty())
{
    cellNum++;
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("Email");
}
UserEntity userObj;
for(int i=0; i<objcets.size();i++)
{
    userObj = (UserEntity) objcets.get(i);
    rowNum++;
    row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    cellNum = 0;

    if(request.getParameter("id")!=null && !request.getParameter("id").isEmpty())
    {
        cellNum++;
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
        cell.setCellValue(userObj.getId());
    }
    if(request.getParameter("fullName")!=null && !request.getParameter("fullName").isEmpty())
    {
        cellNum++;
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
        cell.setCellValue(userObj.getFullName());
    }
    if(request.getParameter("userName")!=null && !request.getParameter("userName").isEmpty())
    {
        cellNum++;
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
        cell.setCellValue(userObj.getUserName());
    }
    if(request.getParameter("department")!=null && !request.getParameter("department").isEmpty())
    {
        cellNum++;
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
        cell.setCellValue(userObj.getDepartment());
    }
    if(request.getParameter("email")!=null && !request.getParameter("email").isEmpty())
    {
        cellNum++;
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
        cell.setCellValue(userObj.getEmail());
    }
```

> But this generate error of class not found for `XSSFWorkbook`, to make it 
>   workable I have to use Maven and inject dependency in pom.xml

I studied for Jxls to, and this also need POI and Meaven and I don't want to make use of Maven. My question is there anyway to export excel sheet without using Maven.

I could not find any blog regarding my question `excel sheet without Maven`.

Comment: You just need to download it from https://poi.apache.org/download.html and add it to the classpath. Apache POI is a simple jar of every other else. So, it only needs to be available on your classpath

Comment: I did that @AmitBera, but I must inject  dependency code in poi.xml, Simply including jar file didnot work- `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;`

Comment: I am really unaware of `poi.xml` . Do you mean `pom.xml`? I believe your project is not a maven project and should not has a `pom.xml`

Comment: sorry ,yes pom.xml

Comment: where to place pom.xml file in java web application ... any idea @AmitBera

Comment: So, your project is a Maven project, right?If yes then there must be pom.xml already exists.  So,  what is stopping to add that dependency to pom.xml? If not a maven project then visit the link to see how to create a maven project http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_SE/Maven.html

Comment: It's not a Maven Project, it's Java Web Application... (Servlet)